# Is it good practise to include an index for an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

I have an array in C that stores strings, and I need to be able to dynamically append to this array. Is it good practise to store the index of this array in a separate variable, or is there some better way to do this? Here's my code.

**First defining these variables**

```
char x[10][10];
int x_index = 0;
```

**Adding strings to this array**

```
strcpy(x[x_index], "hello");
x_index += 1;
strcpy(x[x_index], "world");
x_index += 1;
```

Comment: What do you do if your array is filled?

Comment: @SebastianWalla This code is an example of course, in production `if (x_index <= 10)` would be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the index the length of the array, because what it is: It is the number of valid entries in the array. There are other entries, but they shouldn't be accessed.

It is not only good practice, but in the most cases necessary to keep track of the current size. Otherwise, how would you know ehere to append the next item? In C, this must be done with an extra variable. (Make sure that you can see that array and length belong together with a consistent nomenclature.)

Make sure that the length doesn't exceed the size of the array, 10 in your example. Often, you have to track both, the length and the size, where the size can be a compile-time constant

```
if (xlen < XSIZE) strcpy(x[xlen++], str);
```

(You must also take care not to overflow the 10-character buffer, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

For arrays  in which you need to parse every element anyways (and only parse, with no insertion), it is better to put a special value at the end of the array, such as '\0' in char arrays in order to tell the parsing loop when to stop.